# Calling MinMaxScaler differs between same sets

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have scaled my dataset using the MinMaxScaler form sklearn like this:

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

```
# create a StandardScaler object
self.scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

# fit the scaler to the dataset
self.scaler.fit(self.X_org)

# transform dataset using the scaler
self.X_scalled = pd.DataFrame(self.scaler.transform(self.X_org), columns=self.X_org.columns)

return self.X_scalled
```

However, I am now using the last 10% of the entire dataset for a validation run also scaling the data with the scaler from the training dataset like so:

```
X_input_val_data_scalled = pd.DataFrame(self.scaler.transform(X_input_val_data), columns=X_input_val_data.columns)
```

Now my challenge:

In the training X_org set I get a nicely scaled dataset from 0 to 1. In the scaled validation X dataset I get completely wired data ranging from 7.5 to 8...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's is acutally how it is supposed to be a min-max scaler does the scaling as below:

```
data - min(x) / (max(x) - min(x))
```

where x is the data where the min-max-scaler is trained on. If data belongs to x then data - min(x) is a positive number smaller than max(x) - min(x) hence the ratio will lie between 0 and 1 but otherwise which is the  case in you validation data the ratio doesn't have to be between 0 and 1.

Comment: OK, but how can I then scale the data of a different dataset prior to prediction if the scaler changes everytime I use a different dataset?
Additonally, I tested also the StandardScaler as well as the RobustScaler and all have the effect that the data is not scaled in the same "numbers area" as the original data.

Comment: No way : ) you can't scale something you haven't seen.